# Does 愛 belong to 你 or to 我 in this sentence 你心裡明白 我對你的愛?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

So far I know the language:

你的愛 = your love
我的愛 = my love

Does this sentence `你心裡明白 我對你的愛` mean: In your heart understand me to your love or In your heart understand my love to you?

Answer (score 1):

In 我对你的爱, it should be broke up into 我 [ (对你的) 爱 ].

So 你的爱 is not a sub phrase here.

对你的爱 means love for/to you.

The sentence can be tranlated as: In (your) heart you understand my love to you

Comment: Then I wonder how to say `For/to your love` in Chinese. Can you give me an example?

Comment: @OConnor Maybe "为了你的爱". I cannot quite understand the English "For/to your love".

Comment: Can you make a sentence: "I do this for/to your life". I try to understand the Chinese sentence structure that has `for/to + your/my + noun`.

Comment: For + Your + Life can be translated as 为了 + 你的 + 人生. Example: 我做这件事情，是为了你的人生。(I do this (thing) for your life.)